# How to use the same type as input and return type?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

A simple type like `Location {lat lng}`:

```
  GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'Location',
    fields: {
      lat: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat) },
      lng: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat) },
    }
  });
```

should be able to be used as both input and return type. What's the approach/pattern here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use an (output) type for an input and *vice versa*. You can, however, create a custom scalar. Apollo has a great example of how to do [in their docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/scalars.html#Own-GraphQLScalarType-instance). Then your new CoordinateScalar could easily be used for both input and output.

The other benefit to this approach is you can easily utilize an array for the coordinates if you wanted to (i.e. [34.000, -78.000]) rather than being forced to use an object.