# NestJS GraphQL using the same class as input and output type

Tags: graphql

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508549/how-to-use-the-same-type-as-input-and-return-type), I wanted to know what's the right approach assuming a "code first" paradigm. The following seems to work - using `Location` as both input and output (implicitly generating 2 separate sections in the schema file, derived from the same code).

```
@ObjectType()
@InputType('LocationInput')
export class Location {
    @Field()
    lat: number;

    @Field()
    lon: number;
}
```

I know there's a lot of no-nos about input and output types sharing code - the fact that inputs have various validations that outputs dont, and so on. But I think `Location` is a good exception because in the big picture, let's say `Location` is like String or Int - treated throughout the entire schema as a primitive:

```
@InputType
class MyInput {
    @Field(type => Location)
    location: Location
}

@ObjectType
class MyPlace {
    @Field(type => Location, { nullable: true })
    location?: Location
}
```

Then I don't see why I should not re-use something as simple as a `Location`.

Does anyone else have a take on this?